# jquery select element after append failed

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, append

i'm trying to create jQuery script which loads daa from JSON file, then appends div's with JSON data, and after adding the divs (this works) I'm trying to hide it, using slectors but it returns nothing..

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    //get reference for timeline div, to which will append data
    var timeline = $('#cd-timeline');


    //get JSON data
    $.getJSON('js/qw.json', function(data){
    //console.log(data.items);

            //for each item in json file, will append section with timeline data
            $.each(data.items, function(key,val){ 


                var timelineItem = '<div class="cd-timeline-block">'
                                    + ' <div class="cd-timeline-img cd-picture">'
                                    + '     <img src="img/cd-icon-picture.svg" alt="Picture">'
                                    + ' </div> <!-- cd-timeline-img -->'
                                    + ' <div class="cd-timeline-content">'
                                    + '     <h2>'+val.name+'</h2>'
                                    + '     <p>'+val.description+'</p>'
                                    + '     <p>SKU: '+val.sku+'</p>'
                                    + '     <a href="'+val.url+'" target="_blank" class="cd-read-more">View item</a>'
                                    + '     <span class="cd-date">'+val.date+'</span>'
                                    + ' </div> <!-- cd-timeline-content -->'
                                    + '</div> <!-- cd-timeline-block -->';

                //timeline.append(timelineItem);
                timeline.addChild(timelineItem);

            })
    }); 



    var timelineBlocks = $('.cd-timeline-block');
    var offset = 0.8;
    //hide timeline blocks which are outside the viewport
    hideBlocks(timelineBlocks, offset);


    //on scolling, show/animate timeline blocks when enter the viewport
    $(window).on('scroll', function(){
        (!window.requestAnimationFrame) 
            ? setTimeout(function(){ showBlocks(timelineBlocks, offset); }, 100)
            : window.requestAnimationFrame(function(){ showBlocks(timelineBlocks, offset); });
    });

    function hideBlocks(blocks, offset) {
        blocks.each(function(){
            ( $(this).offset().top > $(window).scrollTop()+$(window).height()*offset ) && $(this).find('.cd-timeline-img, .cd-timeline-content').addClass('is-hidden');
        });
    }

    function showBlocks(blocks, offset) {
        blocks.each(function(){
            ( $(this).offset().top <= $(window).scrollTop()+$(window).height()*offset && $(this).find('.cd-timeline-img').hasClass('is-hidden') ) && $(this).find('.cd-timeline-img, .cd-timeline-content').removeClass('is-hidden').addClass('bounce-in');
        });
    }


});
```

Unfortunately function hidBlocks dosen't work, because timelineBlocks is empty. How to select appended elements to create list so I can do "for each" loop?

Mike

Answer (score 0):

Your code to select the elements is likely happening before the elements have been populated. You need to move your code into the $.getJSON callback function:

```
$.getJSON('js/qw.json', function(data){
//console.log(data.items);

        //for each item in json file, will append section with timeline data
        $.each(data.items, function(key,val){ 


            var timelineItem = '<div class="cd-timeline-block">'
                                + ' <div class="cd-timeline-img cd-picture">'
                                + '     <img src="img/cd-icon-picture.svg" alt="Picture">'
                                + ' </div> <!-- cd-timeline-img -->'
                                + ' <div class="cd-timeline-content">'
                                + '     <h2>'+val.name+'</h2>'
                                + '     <p>'+val.description+'</p>'
                                + '     <p>SKU: '+val.sku+'</p>'
                                + '     <a href="'+val.url+'" target="_blank" class="cd-read-more">View item</a>'
                                + '     <span class="cd-date">'+val.date+'</span>'
                                + ' </div> <!-- cd-timeline-content -->'
                                + '</div> <!-- cd-timeline-block -->';

            //timeline.append(timelineItem);
            timeline.addChild(timelineItem);


        })
        var timelineBlocks = $('.cd-timeline-block');
        var offset = 0.8;
        //hide timeline blocks which are outside the viewport
        hideBlocks(timelineBlocks, offset);
});
```

Comment: It works perfectly! I never tought it would such a stupid mistake 8) thanks a lot!